# Get distinct records from a search query in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

My document structure is as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/fin/deal/1' -d '
{ 
    "deal_key": "500029871", 
    "dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I", 
    "dealPct": "5" ,
    "mvdm": "5" ,
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/post/1' -d '
{ 
    "deal_key": "500029871", 
    "dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I", 
    "dealPct": "5" ,
    "mvdm": "5" ,
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/post/1' -d '
{ 
    "deal_key": "500029871", 
    "dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I2", 
    "dealPct": "5" ,
    "mvdm": "5" ,
}'
```

How can i get a distinct record set from a query in elastic search :My query is as follows :

```
 {
    "_source": [
    "dealname",
    "deal_key"
    ],
    "query": {
    "match": {
    "dealname": {
    "query": "Babson 2004",
    "operator": "and"
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

and the result that i am getting back is:

```
"_source": {
"dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I",
"deal_key": "500029871"
}

"_source": {
"dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I",
"deal_key": "500029871"
}

"_source": {
"dealname": "Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I2",
"deal_key": "500029871"
}
```

But as you see there are only 2 distinct records in the output

1. deal_key 500029871 and dealname Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I
2. deal_key 500029871 and dealname Babson CLO Ltd. 2004-I2

But the output gives me 3 result set .How can i refine this?

In sql scenario you can assume that i have a table with 4 columns and i try to get only 2 column in my query

```
select distinct col1 ,col2 from table1 where col2 = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not have 2 documents in index that are duplicates? If you return _id field and they are different you have 2 different documents in index with same values for dealname and deal_key.

Comment: PLease share the mapping of your index?? `GET /index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Comment: Agreed with @bbergvt, what is the underlying reason for having two documents with exactly the same values in the first place?

Comment: I added my document structure to be more elaborate i have 4 fields in a document but i am trying to retrieve only 2 fields using the source syntax.So based on the  two fields is there are way to get distinct records  in elastic search